# How do I change XFCE tiling to maximize on top edge?

Tags: xfce

In XFCE 4.10, you can enable an option that allows windows to tile automatically when dragged to the edges. The default is to tile to half the screen (half-top, half-bottom, half-left, or half-right). I want to change this so that dragging to the top edge maximizes a window, but I don't see any options in the settings anywhere to change this. Can this be done or am I out of luck here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you're out of luck, unless you want to patch the sources (and possibly also offer the patch upstream). However there are two alternative approaches:

- assign maximizing the window to double clicking on the window header
- use keyboard short-cut (it used do be `Alt+F5`, but I'm not sure what the default is today).

Comment: Ah, I was afraid this would be the case. I already do use the other two alternatives but it's always felt clunky to me since I'm much more used to my mouse. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Since its designed to only go half way.

I use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> And then press <kbd>x</kbd>