# Debian 11 XFCE 4: how to tile windows?

Tags: debian, xfce, tiling-wm

**Context:**

In 2015, [yoshisherry said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209656/keyboard-shortcuts-for-placing-an-xfce4-window-into-the-corner), on UNIX Stack Exchange:

> In windows 7 using Windows Key + Left or Right arrow makes a window take up half the screen.
>
> XFce 4 has the ability to tile either two windows side by side or 4 windows one in each of four corners (bottom left, bottom right, top left, top right).

In 2012, [Michael Cheng said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59180/how-do-i-change-xfce-tiling-to-maximize-on-top-edge), on UNIX Stack Exchange:

> In XFCE 4.10, you can enable an option that allows windows to tile automatically when dragged to the edges. The default is to tile to half the screen (half-top, half-bottom, half-left, or half-right).

**Question:**

In 2023, using `xfcwm 4.16.1-1`, **I ask:**

- how is that possible?

I never was able to do the most basic "left/right" tiling on XFCE on Debian 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Settings > Window Manager Tweaks*, open the *Accessibility* tab and check *Automatically tile windows when moving towards the screen edge*.

This is effective when moving windows towards the left and right sides, and towards the four corners (not bottom or top sides).

I don't see keyboard shortcuts for these actions by default, but you can define them in *Settings > Window Manager* under the *Keyboard* tab, look for actions starting with "Tile window...".

Comment: I checked the settings, as you instructed, and noticed that this is already enabled, and that it works also to bottom or top sides. I changed the settings so it happens at a greater distance, and now I can clearly see it happening. Thank you. But, how about the keyboard shortcuts mentioned by yoshiserry?

Comment: You can define shortcuts but none is configured by default it seems. I've updated the answer accordingly.